# Auto Increment Test Case Number in Excel when New Test Case is Added

Tags: manual-testing, excel

I am stuck with one issue which needs your help. Because of some bad requirement i am supposed to write my test cases in excel. Now Each Test case has a Serial Number. Because the test cases are more than hundred, if i add some test cases in the middle, I have to re-number the subsequent test cases manually. Is there any automatic way like formula or something which can do that for me. Below is the Example.

[image: For Example.]

Now if i add a new test case between Test Case #1 and Test Case #2, I want  newly added case to be numbered as #2 and test case #2 to be renamed as #3 and #3 as #4 automatically, similarly all the subsequent test cases to be re-numbered accordingly. Is it possible to do in excel ? I tried to tweak around with row() and offset() function but not able to figure out the exact solution. I hope my question makes some sense and is clear to understand.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

These numbers are just temporary numbers rather than serial numbers.  It doesn't seem like a good idea to rename (renumber) a test case once it's been defined.  When there's a future failure, it's harder to find results for that test case from a previous run if the test case name/serial number has changed.  Is it necessary to have the test cases numbered in sequential order?  If not, it's easy enough to know what the highest number is and to identify the new case with the next number.  If you delete a test case, don't renumber either.

Comment: Thanks Jean for the inputs. Although let's say it's for management purpose serial numbers are required. Still a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this support article from MS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/automatically-number-rows-HP001154232.aspx) will help you

Comment: the link you've given is not  available(doesn't exist)